# setting textfield vertical alignment, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, alignment, textfield

```
textFormat.align = "center";
```

This, but a vertical equivalent please?
Because of my experience with HTML I have tried

```
textFormat.valign = "middle";
```

But it does not work

Comment: In Flash you cant vertical align a text inside textfield, all you have to do is to place textfield inside a movieclip then use the function Jacob wrote below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't align text vertically automatically in AS3.

You'll have to write your own function to do this.

*eg.*

```
public function verticalAlignTF(tf:TextField):void
{
    tf.y += Math.round((tf.height - tf.textHeight) * .5);
}
```

---

Another option would be using `TLFTextField`, which has a `verticalAlign` property. Just note that TLF has been deprecated by Adobe, so you might run into some issues.